# Role Based Access Control in AngularJS Blur-Admin template

Tags: angularjs, user-roles, rbac, blur-admin

> How to implement **Role Based Access Control** in Blur-Admin template for angularJS? Where to define roles? Which files are concerned?

Answer (score 1):

> **Perfect and Working Solution! This solution basically provides restricted access to the roles allowed for that component.**
>
> define `params` in all of your ***main modules*** in this way - (for example) -

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.components', [
      'BlurAdmin.pages.components.mail',
      // 'BlurAdmin.pages.components.timeline',
      // 'BlurAdmin.pages.components.tree',
      // 'BlurAdmin.pages.components.fileUpload',
    ])
    .config(routeConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main.components', {
        url: '/components',
        template: '<ui-view  autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ui-view>',
        abstract: true,
        title: 'Components',
        sidebarMeta: {
          icon: 'ion-gear-a',
          order: 100,
        },
        authenticate: true,
        params: {                // <-- focusing this one
          authRoles: ['admin']   // <-- roles allowed for this module
        }
      });
  }
})();
```

> Modify ***baSidebar.service.js***, add a new function `getAuthorizedMenuItems` just below `getMenuItems` (for easy understanding). And then just add a single parameter `authRoles` in `defineMenuItemStates()`.
>
> So, `getAuthorizedMenuItems()` will contain following code -

```
this.getAuthorizedMenuItems = function(user) {
    var states = defineMenuItemStates();
    var menuItems = states.filter(function(item) {
        return item.level == 0 && _.includes(item.authRoles, user.role);
    });

    menuItems.forEach(function(item) {
        var children = states.filter(function(child) {
            return child.level == 1 && child.name.indexOf(item.name) === 0;
        });
        item.subMenu = children.length ? children : null;
    });

    return menuItems.concat(staticMenuItems);
};
```

> And updated `defineMenuItemStates()` will be -

```
function defineMenuItemStates() {
    return $state.get()
        .filter(function(s) {
            return s.sidebarMeta;
        })
        .map(function(s) {
            var meta = s.sidebarMeta;
            return {
                name: s.name,
                title: s.title,
                level: ((s.name.match(/\./g) || []).length - 1),
                order: meta.order,
                icon: meta.icon,
                stateRef: s.name,
                authRoles: s.params ? s.params.authRoles : undefined        // <-- added this
            };
        })
        .sort(function(a, b) {
            return (a.level - b.level) * 100 + a.order - b.order;
        });
}
```

> Now, it's time to use the newly added method `getAuthorizedMenuItems` in ***BaSidebarCtrl.js***. Use it this way -

```
// FYI, I got userCreds in BaSidebarCtrl as following -
var userCreds = localStorage.getObject('dataUser');
// note that getMenuItems is just replaced with getAuthorizedMenuItems(userCreds)
// $scope.menuItems = baSidebarService.getMenuItems();
$scope.menuItems = baSidebarService.getAuthorizedMenuItems(userCreds);
```

> So, your `user object` will look something like this -

```
var userCreds = {
    userName: 'test@mail.com',
    passWord: 'testpwd',
    role: 'admin'
};
```

> **That's it!**

Comment: You need to include `Underscore JS` in your project. You can either download it or Here's the cdn link - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js