# blur-admin (lwazevedo) authentication module for submenus

Tags: angularjs, blur-admin

> I'm using RBAC in the blur-admin template in angularjs. Where I've the following scenario - suppose, I've the main side-menu named '***Utilities***', which includes 3 sub-menus. That is, when user clicks on ***Utilities***, he'll see 3 sub-menus - 1) EDI Mapper
> 2) Inventory Mapper
> 3) Invoice Mapper

[image: menu structure]

My ***utilities.module.js*** is -

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.utilities', [
      'ui.select',
      'ngSanitize',
      'BlurAdmin.pages.utilities.ediMapper',
      'BlurAdmin.pages.utilities.inventoryMapper',
      'BlurAdmin.pages.utilities.invoiceMapper',
    ])
    .config(routeConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main.utilities', {
        url: '/utilities',
        template: '<ui-view  autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ui-view>',
        abstract: true,
        title: 'Utilities',
        sidebarMeta: {
          icon: 'ion-hammer',
          order: 100,
        },
        authenticate: true,
        params: {
          authRoles: ['admin', 'inventory-user']
        }
      });
  }

})();
```

> where, `authRoles` are *admin & inventory-user*. That is the ***Utilities*** menu is only visible to *admin & inventory-user*, but not visible to any other users. I want to achieve the same for sub-menus, I've implemented the same logic for the sub menu - ***Inventory Mapper*** as follows -

***inventoryMapper.module.js -***

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.utilities.inventoryMapper', ['angularFileUpload'])
    .config(routeConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main.utilities.inventoryMapper', {
        url: '/inventoryMapper',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/utilities/inventoryMapper/inventoryMapper.html',
        controller: 'inventoryMapperCtrl as vm',
        title: 'Inventory Mapper',
        sidebarMeta: {
          icon: 'ion-ios-pulse',
          order: 100,
        },
        authenticate: true,
        params: {
          authRoles: ['admin', 'inventory-user']
        }
      });
  }
})();
```

***invoiceMapper.module.js -***

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.utilities.invoiceMapper', ['angularFileUpload'])
    .config(routeConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main.utilities.invoiceMapper', {
        url: '/invoiceMapper',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/utilities/invoiceMapper/invoiceMapper.html',
        controller: 'invoiceMapperCtrl as vm',
        title: 'Invoice Mapper',
        sidebarMeta: {
          icon: 'ion-ios-pulse',
          order: 100,
        },
        authenticate: true,
        params: {
          authRoles: ['admin', 'inventory-user']
        }
      });
  }
})();
```

& similar for EDIMapper.module.js with `authRoles: ['admin', 'edi-user']`.

> Now, here, the problem is when I log in with ***inventory-user***, he should only be able to see ***Utilities -> Inventory Mapper*** and not two other sub-menus EDI Mapper & Invoice Mapper under utilities, but **he sees all of them**.
>
> But **currently, all the users are able to see all sub-menus under *`Utilities`* and want to restrict them to their sub-menu only. Other sub-menus should not be accessible/visible to them.**

In short, ***output expected for inventory-user login*** is -
[image: inventory-user sub-menu]

***output expected for invoice-user login*** is -

[image: invoice-user sub-menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem was not fully with the modules, Just added all the roles in ***utilities.module.js***, as - `authRoles: ['admin', 'inventory-user', 'invoice-user', 'edi-user']`. And [referring this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704886/role-based-access-control-in-angularjs-blur-admin-template), updated `getAuthorizedMenuItems()` in ***baSidebar.service.js*** as following -

```
this.getAuthorizedMenuItems = function(user) {
    var states = defineMenuItemStates();
    var menuItems = states.filter(function(item) {
        return item.level == 0 && _.includes(item.authRoles, user.role);
    });

    menuItems.forEach(function(item) {
        var children = states.filter(function(child) {
            // added this - _.includes(child.authRoles, user.role);, here level == 1 means submenus
            return child.level == 1 && child.name.indexOf(item.name) === 0 && _.includes(child.authRoles, user.role);
        });
        item.subMenu = children.length ? children : null;
    });

    return menuItems.concat(staticMenuItems);
};
```